# splunk-connect-for-kubernetes var/log/containers...log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time

Tags: kubernetes, splunk, fluentd

I have a Kubernetes Cluster and I've been trying to forward logs to Splunk with this [splunk-connect-for-kubernetes](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes#prerequisites) repo which is essentially Splunk's own kubernetes-oriented configuration of fluentd.

I initially could see logs in Splunk but they appeared to just be related to the system components but not from the pods that I needed from.

I think I tracked down to the problem in the global `values.yaml` file. I experimented a bit with the `fluentd path` and `containers path` and found that I likely needed to update the `containers pathDest` to the same file path as the pods logs.

It looks like something like this now:

```
fluentd:
    # path of logfiles, default /var/log/containers/*.log
    path: /var/log/containers/*.log
    # paths of logfiles to exclude. object type is array as per fluentd specification:
    # https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#exclude_path
    exclude_path:
    #  - /var/log/containers/kube-svc-redirect*.log
    #  - /var/log/containers/tiller*.log
    #  - /var/log/containers/*_kube-system_*.log (to exclude `kube-system` namespace)

  # Configurations for container logs
  containers:
    # Path to root directory of container logs
    path: /var/log
    # Final volume destination of container log symlinks
    pathDest: /app/logs
```

But now I can see in my the logs for my `splunk-connect` repeated logs like

```
[warn]: #0 [containers.log] /var/log/containers/application-0-tcc-broker-0_application-0bb08a71919d6b.log unreadable. It is excluded and would be examined next time.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem once and changing the path in the values.yaml file helped to solve the problem. It is perfectly described in [this thread](https://community.splunk.com/t5/All-Apps-and-Add-ons/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes-var-log-containers-log-unreadable/m-p/473943):

> Found the solution for my question -
>
> ./splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/charts/splunk-kubernetes-logging/values.yaml: path: `/var/log/containers/*.log` 
> Changed to:
> path: `/var/log/pods/*.log` works to me.

The cited answer may not be readable. Just try changing `/var/log/containers/*.log` to `/var/log/pods/*.log` in your file.

See also [this similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671212/fluentd-log-unreadable-it-is-excluded-and-would-be-examined-next-time).